# How do I create a dummy variable that equals 1 when two id's match each other?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

This is probably really basic but I am new to R.

I have two datasets that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 1
  municipality_code
              <dbl>
1              1001
2              1005
3              1021
```

```
# A tibble: 10 x 1
   municipality_code
               <dbl>
 1              1001
 2              1001
 3              1003
 4              1003
 5              1021
```

I am trying to use the municipality_code on the first tibble to add a dummy on the second tibble that equals 1 when the code matches. This is an example of how the final result should look like:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  municiplity_code dummy
             <dbl> <dbl>
1             1001     1
2             1001     1
3             1003     0
4             1003     0
5             1021     1
```

Comment: Take a look at `help("%in%")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work...

```
first_municipalities<-data.frame("municipality_code"=c(1001,1005,10021))
second_municipalities<-data.frame("municipality_code"=c(1001,1001,1003,1003,10021))

df<-second_municipalities %>%
  mutate(dummy=(municipality_code %in% first_municipalities$municipality_code) %>% as.integer)
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Please take a moment and mark as answered...